# send/receive structs instead of char array

Tags: c++, struct, client, winsock2

i was checking out chat applications in c++ and found this

at server

```
int ServerThread(int ID)
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    char* Recv = new char[256];
    ZeroMemory(Recv, 256);

    // In Send we will copy the content of the struct
    // and after this we will send "Send" to the client
    char* Send = new char[sizeof(Buffer)];
    ZeroMemory(Send, sizeof(Buffer));

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        // Same here!
        if(recv(Connections[ID], Recv, 256, NULL))
        {
            sbuffer.ID = ID;
            memcpy(sbuffer.Message, Recv, 256);
            memcpy(Send, &sbuffer, sizeof(Buffer));

            for(int a = 0; a != ConCounter; a++)
            {
                if(Connections[a] == Connections[ID])
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    send(Connections[a], Send, sizeof(Buffer), NULL);
                }
            }
            ZeroMemory(Recv, 256);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the struct

```
struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};
```

at client

```
int ClientThread()
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    char buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)] = {0};

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        // The server will send a struct to the client
        // containing message and ID
        // But send only accepts a char as buffer parameter
        // so here we need to recv a char buffer and then
        // we copy the content of this buffer to our struct
        if(recv(sConnect, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL))
        {
            memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer));
            cout << "<Client " << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message <<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

server receives char array and use it to fill in "Buffer" struct with the client number to send it to the rest of clients (it obtain the client number as argument from a thread per client call)
what i found interesting was that

```
if(recv(sConnect, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL))
{
    memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer));
    cout << "<Client " << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message <<endl;
}
```

how it could assign a char array (char pointer) to an struct of type Buffer
yeah both are void pointers but what happens behind the scene?
was it because the char array only contains 2 different types it was able to initialize that struct object members with them depending on the type ?

then what if i did the same but with 2 similar types ? ex. 2 ushorts at the same buffer , would it still be able to assign each ? depending on the order of the struct it got ?

Comment: Note that the byte (Char) copy from one buffer to another is no problem. However, the fact that you have an int variable is a problem when being sent over a network if computers do not have matching endians (whether the int is written as 1,2,3,4 or 4,3,2,1...)

Answer (score 2):

The storage for members of a class or struct is just memory, so you can copy the memory of any object into anything with sufficient storage, and then populate a new struct or class of the same type by just copying again. Be careful, there's no type safety when you do this sort of thing.

But, yeah, any class or struct can be stored generically as a sizeof(object) array of char. Char is usually chosen because its size is well-defined, unlike int.

Oh, and the order of the fields in your struct is the order they will be stored in memory.

Comment: Note that classes and structures that have variable members that are complex objects should not be copied with just memcmp(). However, all basic types can indeed be copied, it's just plain memory data.